Como se puede solucionar el siguiente error de Sum en Django
Buenas tardes se me genera el siguiente error en django al realizar una consulta con Sum.
Este es el modelo el cual uso
model.py
class producciones(models.Model):
    codigo=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unidad=models.CharField(max_length=5)
    cantidad=models.FloatField()
    fechaf=models.DateField()

este es la vista
views.py
def principal(request):
  listorden=orden.objects.all().order_by('-codigo')[0:5]
  listprod=producciones.objects.values('descripcion').order_by('descripcion').annotate(prosu=Sum('cantidad'))
  return render(request,"index.html", {"listord":listorden, "listpro":listprod})

Se me genera la siguente Exception
Sum requires values for lower and upper bounds
No se como resolverlo, muchas gracias por adelantado.
